# can the first eigenfunction of the Dirichlet Laplacian have any saddle points

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Let $\Omega$ be a connected, bounded region of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The Laplacian $\Delta$ has a discrete spectrum of functions satisfying
$$\Delta f = \lambda f$$
on $\Omega$ with $f=0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$. I am particularly interested in the first eigenfunction $f_1$, i.e. the one with smallest magnitude eigenvalue.

It is known that $f_1$ does not vanish anywhere inside $\Omega$, and so WLOG is positive over the region. Therefore it is superharmonic and so has no local minima inside $\Omega$. Obviously, it has at least one local maximum. Numerical experiments suggests that it "usually" has no other maxima and no saddle points. Is this always true? If not, are there conditions on $\Omega$ that guarantee it?

Comment: I'd imagine that there'd be two local maxima in a dumbbell shaped region.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Maybe this follows from a symmetry argument? And maybe the convexity of $\Omega$ guarantees the non-existence of saddle points.

Comment: It seem that we can find some useful information in this paper, however, I have not access to it: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=150241

Comment: I found the paper here: http://jjgarmel.webs.ull.es/Articulos/Bull.%20London%20Math.%20Soc.%202003.PDF

Comment: Thanks @Tomás, from that paper we have that convexity and (discrete) rotational symmetry is sufficient. The symmetry condition is much stronger than needed, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a useful recent survey [Geometrical structure of Laplacian eigenfunctions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1278) by Denis S. Grebenkov and Binh-Thanh Nguyen. Quote:

> a level set of the first Dirichlet eigenfunction  on a bounded convex domain in $\mathbb R^d$ is itself convex [274].

Predictably, the reference is to Bernhard Kawohl's book *Rearrangements and Convexity of Level Sets in PDE*.

Comment: The book of Kawohl does not seem to contain the exact statement. The statement follows from the log concavity of f which follows from work of Brascamp and Lieb ("Some inequalities for Gaussian measures..."). A short proof is given in Appendix B of a paper by  Singer, Wong, Yau, and Yau. http://www.numdam.org/article/ASNSP_1985_4_12_2_319_0.pdf